# Laravel exel export table with a border

Tags: excel, laravel, export

I have cell values

[image]

using this code I was able to fill only the required cells

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Reservation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnWidths;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\setAlignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;
use DB;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnWidths, WithStyles, WithEvents
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $type = DB::table('reservations')->select('id', 'pnr', 'passenger_count', 'firstname', 'status')->get();
        return $type ;
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:G8')->applyFromArray([
                        'borders' => [
                            'allBorders' => [
                                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
                                'color' => ['argb' => '#000000'],
                            ],
                        ],


                    ]);
               }
        ];
    }


}
```

but my code only fills cells "A1:G8"

[image]

How can I make it fill the entire value with borders despite the number of values

like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add borders to all cells in the Excel sheet, you have to modify the code as follows:

```
return [
    AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
        $lastColumn = $event->sheet->getHighestColumn();
        $lastRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();

        $range = 'A1:' . $lastColumn . $lastRow;

        $event->sheet->getStyle($range)->applyFromArray([
            'borders' => [
                'allBorders' => [
                    'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
                    'color' => ['argb' => '#000000'],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
];
```